# Stiff differential equation and shooting

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm trying to solve the differential equation: $$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}
+\frac{3}{x}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\partial \hat{U}}{\partial y},\quad \hat{U}=y^2 - y^3 +\kappa y^4 $$ with boundary conditions, $$ \left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{x = 0} = 0,\quad y(\infty) = 0. $$

Here, $\kappa\in (-\infty, 1/4)$. See [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9804308) for more context, and the expected results for numerical integration in Fig. 2. It's my understanding that the best way to tackle a problem of this type is with a shooting method. Below is the code I've tried to use:

```
U[y_] = y^2 - y^3 + k*y^4;
dU[y_] = U'[y];

x0 = 10^-2; xf = 10^3; k = 0.1;

sols = NDSolve[{y''[x] + 3*y'[x]/x == dU[y[x]], y[xf] == 0, y'[x0] == 0}, 
y, {x, x0, xf}, 
Method -> {"Shooting", 
"StartingInitialConditions" -> {y[xf] == 0.0, y'[xf] == 0.01}}]
```

I've tried adjusting the "StartingInitialConditions", but I always end up with

```
At x == (some number), step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected
```

How can I avoid this? What are some general tips for selecting the initial conditions to avoid the above problem?

Comment: It's a singularity, not stiffness, not that it matters that much. But maybe this will help: `Table[NDSolveValue[{y''[x] + 3*y'[x]/x == dU[y[x]], y[xf] == 0, y'[xf] == yf, WhenEvent[Abs[y[x]] > 10, "StopIntegration"]}, y, {x, x0, xf}], {yf, -1, 1, 1/10}] // 
 ListLinePlot[MapThread[Tooltip, {#, Range[-1, 1, 1/10]}]] &`. It shows the solutions in a neighborhood of `y'[xf] = 0`. The only solution I've found is the zero solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that was helpful. However, the initial conditions should be `y[xf] == 0, y'[x0] == 0` rather than what you've  specified.

Comment: `y[xf] == 0, y'[x0] == 0` are *boundary conditions* (BCs). The shooting method works by solving the initial value problem with *initial conditions* `y[xf] == y0, y'[xf] == yp0` and varies `y0` and `yp0` until the BCs are satisfied. Of course, in this case, it makes sense to have `y0` fixed at `y[xf] == 0` and just vary the condition for `y'[xf]`, which I called `yf` in the comment's code. (Should have called it `ypf`, perhaps.) Anyway, by varying `yf`, you can see how easy it is to satisfy the BCs (or not). BTW, around `yf = -10.41494237889491447646150845685` seems promising if badly unstable.